# Django Imagekit - how to get the url not in the template?

Tags: python, django, imagekit

I have been using django imagekit without any problems in the templates but now I need to get the url in the view not the template, following this example in the imagekit docs:

```
source_file = open('/path/to/myimage.jpg')
image_generator = Thumbnail(source=source_file)
result = image_generator.generate()
```

So I did this:

```
course_img = open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+str(course.image), 'rb+')     
image_generator = myapp_images.Thumbnail100x100(source=course_img)
result = image_generator.generate()
```

And then, I try to get the url from the "result" variable, but I don't know how:

```
details_html += "<img class='img-rounded' src='"+ str(result) +"'/>
```

I have been trying with `str(result), result.url, result.name`, etc... with no luck, any idea how to get it?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution from the imagekit author in the [google imagekit group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-imagekit/yNzrsNAn8As):

In my case I wanted to interact with the Cache File, in order to do that we have to wrap my generator with an `ImageCacheFile`, like this:

```
from imagekit.cachefiles import ImageCacheFile

image_generator = myapp_images.Thumbnail00x100(source=course.image)
result = ImageCacheFile(image_generator)
```

so the `result` object it is what I was expecting, now I can read the url just using `result.url`.

Comment: This is correct. For anyone wondering what is `myapp_images`, I suppose this is where you keep custom generators. You could use `from imagekit.generatorlibrary import Thumbnail` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Generator itself doesn't allow you to do that on the fly, it generates file-like object, which means it doesn't save the file on disk, which means no filename and so, no URL name..

Either you save the object and generate url manually or you can use `ImageCacheFile` like this:

```
from imagekit.cachefiles import ImageCacheFile

file = ImageCacheFile(image_generator, name='my_image.thumb.jpg')
file.generate()

print file.url
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mario but I couldn´t make it work, I got some problems with that "name=´the.jpg´" atributte, it was close by the way and thanks again for your time answering here. Cheers.